# Reading lines from a file in Jython

Tags: python, file, io, jython

Ok, I know this is going to sound like a homework question (because it kind of is), but our lecturer has thrown us in the deep end with this and I need a little help, my google-fu is failing.
As part of an assignment I need to read in data from a text file, and copy each line of the text file into an array/list. What I've done is not working.
What I have so far:

```
def main():
  file = open(pickAFile())

  lines = []
  index = 0

  for line in file:
    lines[index] = line
    index = index + 1
```

But this comes back with:
*The error value is: list assignment index out of range Sequence index out of range. The index you're using goes beyond the size of that data (too low or high). For instance, maybe you tried to access OurArray[10] and OurArray only has 5 elements in it.*

Any help would be most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line `lines[index] = line`. There is nothing in `lines[0]` in the first iteration.

You need to change this line to `lines.append(line)`, and you don't need to keep track after `index`, so your whole code should look like:

```
def main():
    file = open(pickAFile())

    lines = []

    for line in file:
        lines.append(line)
```

`append` adds the parameter that it receives to the last index in the list that it is called with, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: Worth explaining how `append` works or at least linking the docs, since OP is relatively new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extend `list` like this, if your list is empty (`lines = []`), then `lines[index]` is trying to access a non existing index and thus throws an error.

If you want to append something to your list, use the [append](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) function:

```
lines.append(line)
```

But if you want to read all the lines in a file, you'd better use the `readlines` method:

```
lines = file.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

To read file into list you can try:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

or

```
lines = [line for line in open("file.txt")]
```

Here each line will have `\n` characters. To remove that use, `line.rtrim('\n')`